# .htaccess MAMP difference to environment

Tags: mod-rewrite, mamp

I'm building my site on MAMP, after a couple of days I finally got an .htaccess file to work after my will. But now when I upload to live environment it doesn't behave the same! Is there different versions? Is it because of error in my file that MAMP handles automatic?

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on dev and prod environments

Answer (score 0):

Check if mod_rewrite is enabled in your live environment.